# hide a legend with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose for example I have

```
ggplot(data=PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight, fill=group)) + geom_boxplot()
```

and I don't want to display the legend. What is the simplest way to hide or remove the legend from a plot?

Comment: Why did you even ask this question if you were able to answer it yourself?

Comment: @Jaap: that is actually [encouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250204/can-you-answer-your-own-questions-on-stack-overflow) on SO -- although perhaps not if the question is itself a duplicate ...

Comment: I couldn't find an answer here, so when I figured it out I thought the answer could be helpful for others

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `theme(legend.position="none")`, like this:

```
ggplot(data=PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight, fill=group)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

([source](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_%28ggplot2%29/#removing-the-legend))